# Why does this output 234 in CPP

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename E, typename R>
R multiply(T x, E y, R r) {
    return static_cast<typeof(r)>(x * y);
}

int main() {
    double x = multiply(6, 80, uint8_t());
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

hey there, the following codes output is 224, but how is that possible if 6*80 = 480. a follow up question would be "how could I write this better"?

Comment: `uint8_t` has a value range of 0…255. You cannot represent anything outside that range using a `uint8_t`.

Comment: Note: `assert((480 % 256) == 224)`

Comment: can u explain why? like not just the formula of 224

Comment: Are you asking why the value 480 can not be stored in an 8-bit integer?  Are you asking why the lowest 8 bits of 480 produce the value 234?

Comment: Do you mean why 8 bits can only represent 0..255?

Comment: like why exactly the result is 224

Comment: What does " how can I write this better" mean? What do you want? What are you trying in the first place

Comment: Note that `typeof` is not in the standard C++. Use `decltype`.

Answer (score 4):

> like why exactly the result is 224

The value 480 has this representation in binary:

```
1 1110 0000
```

That's 9 bits.  The 1s represent 256 + 128 + 64 + 32, which is 480.

If you store this value in an **eight bit** variable, it can only hold **the lowest 8 bits**:

```
  1110 0000
```

The value of this binary number is 128 + 64 + 32.  In other words, 224.

It's exactly 256 shy of the original value, because a `uint8_t` does not have a bit to represent 256.

Any non-negative value `x` stored in  a `uint8_t` will have the value `x % 256`.

> how can I write this better?

Store the result in a variable that can represent 480.

For example,

```
double x = multiply(6, 80, uint16_t());
```

Or, for simplicity, since you're already converting the result to a `double`:

```
double x = multiply(6, 80, double());
```

Answer (score 3):

> why is this output 224 [sic]

Because you demanded the result to be a byte, and 480 is larger than a byte, so it will roll over.

> how can I write this better?

Pretty much any other way, really. For example, you can simply multiply your values, you don't need that function.

If you insist on a templated function, use the same type for the operands. You gain nothing by having three different types if you're multiplying numbers:

```
template <typename T>
T multiply(T x, T y, T r) {
    return x * y;
}
```

called like:

```
auto res = multiply<uint8_t>(6, 80); // 224
auto res = multiply(6, 80);          // 480
```